# Kill root process from PHP

Tags: php, shell, rhel7

I want to kill a root process from PHP. I am running PHP in root user.
 In my senerio, PHP will execute shell script to killing root process.

Shell Script: kill.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
ps -ef | grep node | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill
```

In PHP:

```php
exec('./kill.sh 2>&1');
```

It is  showing: kill: sending signal to 15819 failed: Operation not permitted

How to kill the root process from PHP??

Answer (score 0):

PHP is usually run with a web server / php-fpm process, which is rarely run with the root user. But killing a process require the user that runs the kill command with the permission to control that specific process (either the user own the process or the user is root). A user can only be sure to have that permission if he / she has root permission when killing the process.

In order for the php script to run kill.sh with root permission, you may add [setuid bit](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits) to the `kill.sh` script.

```sh
sudo chown root kill.sh
sudo chmod g+s kill.sh
```

Please note that by setting the setuid bit, the `kill.sh` can be run by virtually anybody in the system to kill any process. You should be extremely careful.

Comment: I change the file permission and  now permission is : -rwxrwxrwx+ 1 root root 86 Sep 16 14:33 kill.sh. But still not able to run it from PHP

Comment: `xargs -r kill -s SIGKILL` may be added in Shell script. Also, absolute path of the executable script may be tried.